Compactness of a parametrized solution set in a Hilbert space
I have a question regarding the compactness of a certain parametrized solution set. I am thankful for any help or suggestions to literature.
In general I am intersted in the set of solutions of the eqaution
$\lambda Ax + (1-\lambda)Bx = 0$,
where $A$ and $B$ are monotone operators on a Hilbert space and $\lambda \in [0,1]$.
Notation:
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real Hilbert space with inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ and induced norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$. For $\varepsilon > 0$ denote the open ball with radius $\varepsilon$ by $B_{\varepsilon}(x) = \lbrace y \in \mathcal{H} : \lVert y - x \rVert < \varepsilon \rbrace$. Define for $T:\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ the set of zeros $\mathrm{zer}(T) = \lbrace x \in \mathcal{H} : Tx = 0 \rbrace$. We denote the projection of a point $x \in \mathcal{H}$ on a closed convex set $K \subset \mathcal{H}$ by $proj_K(x) = argmin_{y \in K} \lVert y - x \rVert^2$.
Setup:
Let $A, B: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ be maximal monotone Lipschitz continuous operators, i.e., both satisfy

$\langle Ax - Ay, x - y \rangle \ge 0$, for all $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$
$ \lVert Ax - Ay \rVert \le L \lVert x - y \rVert$, for all $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$

For $\lambda \in [0,1]$ define
$S(\lambda) = \mathrm{zer}(\lambda A + (1-\lambda) B)$
Assume there exists $M \ge 0$ such that $B_M(0) \cap S(\lambda) \neq \emptyset$ for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Define
$\bar{S} = \lbrace proj_{S(\lambda)}(0) : \lambda \in [0,1] \rbrace$.
Question: Is the set $\overline{S}$ precompact?

It looks to me that $B_M(0)\cap S(\lambda) \neq \phi$ for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$ implies $\overline{S}\subseteq B_M(0)$.

Yes this is true. However this does not seem to help to much on its own since $B_M(0)$ is not precompact in my setting.
